# What is difference between NSArray and normal Array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I am new in Objective-c. I am feeling confuse between NSArray and normal Array. Please tell me when to use NSArray and when to use normal array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray` is an Objective-C object that stores a collection of `NSObject`s (such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDictionary`, etc)

Example:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"String 1",@"String 2",@"String 3"];
```

(the above uses Objective-C literals to define an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` -- see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Objective-C is built on top of C, which also includes arrays (lowercase 'a'), which are commonly used as  collections of primitive data types (such as `int`, `char`, etc), for example.

Example:

```
int myArray[10] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
```

C arrays can also be used to store pointers, which could point to objects in memory, as pointed out by CRD/Jef in the comments.

Both have cases where they are useful, but the one of the common reasons to go with one or the other would be whether you need to store objects or primitives.  Although as pointed out above, C arrays can handle objects, it is generally more common practice and more convenient to use `NSArray` to handle that.

Also, `NSArray` has a bunch of convenience functions (such as `count` and `lastObject`) that can help you with the data.  See the Apple documentation on `NSArray` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/

Note: if you need an array with a varying size, look into `NSMutableArray`

Comment: would you please give any example?

Comment: @jn_pdx - C style arrays can store objects, and ARC will handle them (ARC doesn't support structs and unions).

Comment: @CRD actually C arrays can hold pointers.., which being an address in memory, could be just about anything :)