# How to use int[] type in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, invoke

### I have two question , please help .

### Firstly :

how to invoke method if the method's parameters contain int[] type ?

Look this code :

```
- (void)tearDown {
    [self func:@[@3,@4,@5]] ; // **Error !**
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)func:(int[])encodeFormat {

    unsigned int encodeFormatLength = sizeof(encodeFormat) / sizeof(int) ;
        for( unsigned int index = 0 ; index < encodeFormatLength ; index++ ) {
            int value = encodeFormat[index] ;
            printf("%d\n",value) ;
        }
}
```

### Secondly :

how to solve the Xcode's warning message ?

Look this code :

```
- (void)func:(int[])encodeFormat {

    // Warning : 
    // Sizeof on array function parameter will return sizeof 'int *' instead of 'int []'
    unsigned int encodeFormatLength = sizeof(encodeFormat) / sizeof(int) ;
}
```

Comment: I know the question here is about Objective C, but the rules are the same in C.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c is a better question to look at

Comment: The difference between an array and an `NSArray` is more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27874283/620197

Comment: thanks , I can solve the first question . But how to solve the second question  ?